# How to group json objects by using keys of sub value objects using jq

Tags: json, shell, command-line-interface, jq

I have a json file in the format

```
{
  "hello": [
    {
      "name": "var1",
      "value": "1234"
    },
    {
      "name": "var2",
      "value": "2356"
    },
    {
      "name": "var3",
      "value": "2356"
    }
  ],
  "hi": [
    {
      "name": "var1",
      "value": "3412"
    },
    {
      "name": "var2",
      "value": "2563"
    },
    {
      "name": "var3",
      "value": "4256"
    }
  ],
  "bye": [
    {
      "name": "var1",
      "value": "1294"
    },
    {
      "name": "var2",
      "value": "8356"
    },
    {
      "name": "var3",
      "value": "5356"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to convert this object into this format

```
{
  "output": [
    {
      "var1": {
        "hello": "1234",
        "hi": "3412",
        "bye": "1294"
      }
    },
    {
      "var2": {
        "hello": "2356",
        "hi": "2563",
        "bye": "8356"
      }
    },
    {
      "var3": {
        "hello": "2356",
        "hi": "4256",
        "bye": "5356"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

so far i've tried multiple ways using to_entries and map functions in jq to create the contents inside the output variable
`jq 'to_entries | map(.value[]| . += {"key_v" : (.key)} )' input.json > output.json` this is the closest i came to a solution

- extracting keys and add to the key value pair of the object
- use map(select()) to group by keys
  but i am getting errors in both the steps such as cannot index array with string name or string value.

Comment: For your desired `"output"` are you showing what you truly want for `"var2"` and `"var3"` values for `"hello"`, `"hi"`, and `"bye"`?  I.e., you currently show the values from `"var1"` repeated and lose the values from the original input.

Comment: ... for example, would you prefer `"output"` as shown in this [jqplay.org example](https://jqplay.org/s/kbGHqzTpJGP)?

Comment: the values will be maintained from the original json

Comment: So, you want the `"var1"`, `"var2"`, and `"var3"` to all have an identical object as their values?

Comment: sorry for the confusion I updated the question

Comment: Looks like you want to `JOIN`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't win a beauty contest, but it works:

```
with_entries(.value |= from_entries)
| with_entries(.key as $key | .value[] |= {($key):.})
| reduce .[] as $item ({}; . * $item)
| {output: to_entries | map({(.key):.value})}
```

With a single call to `with_entries`:

```
with_entries(.key as $key | .value |= (from_entries | map_values({($key):.})))
| reduce .[] as $item ({}; . * $item)
| {output: to_entries | map({(.key):.value})}
```

Output:

```
{
  "output": [
    {
      "var1": {
        "hello": "1234",
        "hi": "3412",
        "bye": "1294"
      }
    },
    {
      "var2": {
        "hello": "2356",
        "hi": "2563",
        "bye": "8356"
      }
    },
    {
      "var3": {
        "hello": "2356",
        "hi": "4256",
        "bye": "5356"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: OP wants all `var(n)` in their separate object.

Comment: [jqplay.org for 1st solution.](https://jqplay.org/s/Osuom9Zerlz) [jqplay.org for 2nd solution.](https://jqplay.org/s/opt6ES2CE29)

Comment: @rickhg12hs I think it is unnecessary to copy-paste answer content to jqplay, for several reasons: 1) jqplay permalinks become stale 2) everybody can do it easily themselves

Comment: I think you're right - it's not necessary.  I use the solutions to help learn `jq` (sprinkling `debug` and/or commenting out `#` portions is great for seeing intermediate results) and perhaps other _learners_ might find them useful too, especially if they don't know about [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/). I didn't know the links become stale.  :(

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution is readily obtained if the following stream-oriented "coalesce" function is used:

```
# s is assumed to be a stream of objects for which
# the values for each distinct key are summable.
# Output: a single object formed by adding 
# the $v values of each distinct key.
def coalesce(s):
  reduce (s | to_entries[]) as {key: $k, value: $v} ({};
    .[$k] += $v);
```

The solution is now simply:

```
coalesce(to_entries[]
         | .key as $key
         | .value[]
         | {(.name): {($key): .value}})
| {output: [.]}
```

Comment: [jqplay.org for solution.](https://jqplay.org/s/M1Axj7XGM4r)

Answer (score 2):

This generates what's expected :

```
{ output:
    to_entries |
    map(.key as $key|.value|map(.nn=.name|.name=$key)) |
    add |
    group_by(.nn) |
    map({(first|.nn) : from_entries})
}
```

Comment: [jqplay.org for solution.](https://jqplay.org/s/l8VrDyjMfid)